# When Refresh the webbrowser Component got a blank page?

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

Why I got a blank page when I Refresh the web page in webbrowser.

btw here is some of my code in webbrowser:

```
        webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
        if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.Write(String.Empty);
        }

        webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = true;
        webBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<h1>Hallo</h1>";
```

I have disable keyboard shortcut to denied F5 button but I guess that's not a good solution.

Comment: what is in the "html" variable? where do you do that code snippet?

Comment: it's html text to show in browser

Comment: if I do a webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<h1>Hallo</h1>" and later do manually a refresh there is still a hello in the webbrowser

Comment: I think you do anything else. I tested it on a clean project and it works!

Comment: well, I create new Project `public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<h1>Hallo</h1>";

        }` still not work :|

Answer (score 1):

Please check some times html variable may initialized to blank inside the refresh code block

Comment: I am using this for now: `webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<h1>Hallo</h1>"`